# Raise ClientException(required_message.format(attribute)) praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' missing

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I am not sure how to make this work. I also can't find client_id in my app. I just see the app secret there:

```
>>> import praw
>>> r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='custom data mining framework',
... site_name='lamiastella')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 101, in __init__
    raise ClientException(required_message.format(attribute))
praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' missing. 
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to the `Reddit` class constructor, or as an environment variable.
```

here is my `praw.ini` file which I am not sure if it's correct or has all the necessary fields:

```
[lamiastella]
domain: www.monajalal.com
user: lamiastella
pswd: mypassword
```

any help is really appreciated.

**Can I retrieve images using praw as well from reddit or what do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused from a missing `client_id` (which is your unique API key and secret for the Reddit API) in your `praw.ini` file or in your Python script.

In your script you could have something like:

```
r.set_oauth_app_info(client_id='stJlUSUbPQe5lQ',
...                      client_secret='DoNotSHAREWithANYBODY',
...                      redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:65010/'
...                                   'authorize_callback')
```

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/oauth.html?highlight=client_id#step-2-setting-up-praw

Or set up in the `praw.ini` file as described in the link below:

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/configuration_files.html#configuration-variables

If you have already signed up for access to the reddit API, it says:

https://www.reddit.com/wiki/api

> OAUTH Client ID(s) *
>
> - if you don't have yet, please email api@reddit.com when received or when you add additional

You can get your `client_id` from your app in:
https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps

[image]

In this example from their documentation (under the API app title): the `client_id=p-jcoLKBynTLew`

Comment: My r is not set hence I can not use it. I have error in `r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='custom data mining framework',
... site_name='lamiastella')` where r is assigned! I was asking this question to see where I can find client_id exactly and how to set up praw.ini

Comment: Updated where you can find the `client_id`

Comment: Thank you so much for the screenshot. It made it clear to me where the client_id is :)

Comment: This answer pertains to PRAW<4. The error message in the question belongs to PRAW4, which does not have a `set_oauth_app_info` as these values are passed directly to the `Reddit` class initializer.

Comment: @ode2k seems you are familiar with praw. can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578098/headers-authorization-bearer-accesstokenaccess-token-user-agent ? thanks