# headers = {"Authorization": "bearer " + accessToken['access_token'], "User-Agent": userAgent} KeyError: 'access_token'

Tags: python, authorization, access-token, reddit, praw

I found this code in this [SO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366388/get-all-comments-from-a-specific-reddit-thread-in-python) however when I run it I get this error:

in redcom.py I have:

```
import time
import requests
import requests.auth
import praw

username = 'myusername'
userAgent = "reddit natural language processing " + username
clientId = 'myclientid'
clientSecret = "myclientsecret"
password = "mypasswd"
#app_uri = http://127.0.0.1:65010/authorize_callback


def getPraw():
  return praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=clientId, client_secret=clientSecret)

global accessToken
accessToken = None

def getAccessToken():
  client_auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(clientId, clientSecret)
  post_data = {"grant_type": "password", "username": username, "password": password}
  headers = {"User-Agent": userAgent}
  response = requests.post("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token", auth=client_auth, data=post_data, headers=headers)
  return response.json()

def makeRequest(apiUrl, useGet=True):
  global accessToken
  if accessToken is None:
    accessToken = getAccessToken()
  headers = {"Authorization": "bearer "  + accessToken['access_token'], "User-Agent": userAgent}
  if useGet:
    response = requests.get(apiUrl, headers=headers)
  else:
    response = requests.post(apiUrl, headers=headers)
  time.sleep(1.1)
  responseJson = response.json()
  if 'error' in responseJson:
    if responseJson['error'] == 401:
      print "Refreshing access token"
      time.sleep(1.1)
      accessToken = getAccessToken()
      headers = {"Authorization": "bearer "  + accessToken['access_token'], "User-Agent": userAgent}
      time.sleep(1.1)
      response = requests.get(apiUrl, headers=headers)
      responseJson = response.json()
  return responseJson


global prawReddit
prawReddit = praw.Reddit(user_agent=userAgent, client_id=clientId, client_secret=clientSecret)

# Gets any number of posts
def getPosts(subredditName, numPosts=1000):
  global prawReddit
  subreddit = prawReddit.get_subreddit(subredditName)

  postGetter = praw.helpers.submissions_between(prawReddit, subreddit)

  postArray = []
  numGotten = 0
  while numGotten < numPosts:
    postArray.append(postGetter.next())
    numGotten += 1

  return postArray






# Get all comments from a post
# Submission is a praw submission, obtained via:
# r = redApi.getPraw()
# submission = r.get_submission(submission_id='2zysz7') # (or some other submission id, found via https://www.reddit.com/r/test/comments/2zysz7/ayy/ - the thing after /comments/)
# comments = redApi.getComments(submission)
def getComments(submission):
  requestUrl = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/' + submission.subreddit.url + 'comments/article?&limit=1000&showmore=true&article=' + submission.id
  allData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
  articleData = allData[0]
  comments = allData[1]
  curComments = comments['data']['children']

  resultComments = getCommentsHelper(curComments, submission.name, submission)

  return resultComments




# Print out the tree of comments
def printTree(comments):
  return printTreeHelper(comments, "")


def printTreeHelper(comments, curIndentation):
  resultString = ""
  for comment in comments:
    resultString += curIndentation + comment['data']['body'].replace("\n", "\n" + curIndentation) + "\n"
    if not comment['data']['replies'] == "":
      resultString += printTreeHelper(comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'], curIndentation + "  ")
  return resultString

# Get all comments as a single array  
def flattenTree(comments):
  allComments = []
  for comment in comments:
    allComments.append(comment)
    if not comment['data']['replies'] == "":
      allComments += flattenTree(comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'])
  return allComments





# Utility functions for getComments
def expandCommentList(commentList, submission):

  curComments = commentList
  allComments = {}
  while True:
    thingsToExpand = []
    nextComments = []
    allParents = {}
    for comment in curComments:
      if comment['kind'] == "more":
        thingsToExpand += comment['data']['children']
      else:
        if comment['data']['body'][:len("If they are shipping")] == "If they are shipping":
          print comment
        allComments[comment['data']['name']] = comment

    if len(thingsToExpand) == 0:
      curComments = []
      break

    curComments = []
    if not len(thingsToExpand) == 0:
      print "total things to expand: " + str(len(thingsToExpand))
      for i in range(0, len(thingsToExpand)/100+1):
        curCommentIds = thingsToExpand[i*100:min((i+1)*100, len(thingsToExpand))]
        requestUrl = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/api/morechildren.json?api_type=json&link_id=' + submission.name + '&limit=1000&showmore=true&children=' + ",".join(curCommentIds)
        curData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
        if 'json' in curData and 'data' in curData['json']:
          curComments += curData['json']['data']['things']
        print (i+1)*100


  for comment in curComments:
    allComments[comment['data']['name']] = comment

  return allComments.values()


def lookForMore(comment):
  if comment['kind'] == "more":
    return True
  if not comment['data']['replies'] == "":
    for reply in comment['data']['replies']['data']['children']:
      if lookForMore(reply):
        return True
  return False

def getCommentsHelper(curComments, rootId, submission):

  allComments = expandCommentList(curComments, submission)

  commentMap = {}
  for comment in allComments:
    commentMap[comment['data']['name']] = comment


  allRootComments = []
  for comment in allComments:
    if comment['data']['parent_id'] == rootId:
      allRootComments.append(comment)
    elif comment['data']['parent_id'] in commentMap:
      parentComment = commentMap[comment['data']['parent_id']]
      if parentComment['data']['replies'] == "":
        parentComment['data']['replies'] = {'data': {'children': []}}
      alreadyChild = False
      for childComment in parentComment['data']['replies']['data']['children']:
        if childComment['data']['name'] == comment['data']['name']:
          alreadyChild = True
          break
      if not alreadyChild:
        parentComment['data']['replies']['data']['children'].append(comment)
    else:
      print "pls halp"

  completedComments = []
  needMoreComments = []

  for comment in allRootComments:
    if not comment['data']['replies'] == "" or comment['kind'] == 'more':
      hasMore = lookForMore(comment)

      if hasMore:
        needMoreComments.append(comment)
      else:
        replyComments = getCommentsHelper(comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'], comment['data']['name'], submission)
        comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'] = replyComments
        completedComments.append(comment)
    else:
      completedComments.append(comment)
  for comment in needMoreComments:
    requestUrl = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/' + submission.subreddit.url + 'comments/article?&limit=1000&showmore=true&article=' + submission.id + "&comment=" + comment['data']['id']
    allData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
    articleData = allData[0]
    comment = allData[1]['data']['children'][0]
    if comment['data']['replies'] == "":
      completedComments.append(comment)
    else:
      comments = comment['data']['replies']['data']['children']
      actualComments = getCommentsHelper(comments, comment['data']['name'], submission)
      comment['data']['replies']['data']['children'] = actualComments
      completedComments.append(comment)

  return completedComments
```

and in tester.py I have:

```
import redcom
r = redcom.getPraw()
submission = r.get_submission(submission_id='z1c9z') 
comments = redcom.getComments(submission)
```

The error is:

```
$ python tester.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 4, in <module>
    comments = redcom.getComments(submission)
  File "/home/jalal/computer_vision/reddit/redcom.py", line 80, in getComments
    allData = makeRequest(requestUrl)
  File "/home/jalal/computer_vision/reddit/redcom.py", line 31, in makeRequest
    headers = {"Authorization": "bearer "  + accessToken['access_token'], "User-Agent": userAgent}
KeyError: 'access_token'
```

Comment: Yea this is the error I was running into too - my code works good for smaller things, but for things that are many thousand comments (yours is 18011 comments, for example) it keeps getting this error. Did you manage to fix this?